# Rabbitmq 2.2 not working on Snow Leopard (SSL errors)

Tags: erlang, openssl, osx-snow-leopard, rabbitmq

When I start rabbitmq, I see the following message:

> ```
> Activating RabbitMQ plugins ...
> *WARNING* Undefined function crypto:des3_cbc_decrypt/5  
> *WARNING* Undefined function crypto:start/0  
> *WARNING* Undefined function ssl:close/1  
> *WARNING* Undefined function ssl:controlling_process/2  
> *WARNING* Undefined function ssl:peercert/1  
> *WARNING* Undefined function ssl:peername/1  
> *WARNING* Undefined function ssl:recv/3  
> *WARNING* Undefined function ssl:send/2  
> *WARNING* Undefined function ssl:sockname/1  
> *WARNING* Undefined function ssl:ssl_accept/3    
> 0 plugins activated:
> ```

I followed the advice [here](http://old.nabble.com/2.1.1%3A-no-such-file-or-directory-crypto.app-message-prevents-broker-from-starting-td30011026.html) to install openssl and recompile erlang with a `--with-ssl` path set.

When I recompiled erlang, I used the following .configure:

```
./configure \  
    --prefix=/usr/local/erlang/R13B04 \  
    --enable-smp-support \  
    --enable-threads \  
    --enable-darwin-64bit \  
    --with-ssl=/usr/include/openssl
```

It compiled fine.  Then, just in case, I reinstalled rabbit from macports.  I still get the error.  Am I using the wrong path for `--with-ssl`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely because your version of erlang (which MacPorts will automatically install when installing RabbitMQ since it has a dependency on it) doesn't include the necessary SSL dependencies. To fix this, run:

```
sudo port sync
sudo port install erlang +ssl
```

The `+ssl` is key. If you run into any issues during the erlang w/ ssl installation, fix the issues then run the command again (I had to force activation of perl5 during my installation, the command to run is displayed in terminal before the build exits).

Once you do that you should no longer get the warnings.

Here's some [reference information](http://www.digitalassassin.com/development/macports-rabbitmq-erlang-w-ssl-on-mac-osx-snow-leopard/).

Answer (score 1):

This happened me too. All the guides and tutorials I found were using rabbitmq-server 1.7.2 so I downgraded to this using the SVN method described @  https://trac.macports.org/wiki/howto/InstallingOlderPort

Working well now.